# Windows 10 privacy concerns for other accounts on same computer

Tags: windows, privacy, windows-10

What are the privacy concerns for a **local** account on a Windows 10 computer, which has all settings set to "private", if an additional "Microsoft" account is being used on the same computer with disregard for any privacy issues? Is one user's personal information being sent to Microsoft through another user?

The question refers to the Windows privacy issues only. Not the possibility of virus infections etc.

Comment: All Microsoft products are not opensouce, so if a user trusts something like Windows 10 there is nothing further he has to worry about.

Comment: Are you asking for what Microsoft claims or what a source and network traffic analysis reveals?

Comment: Are you asking if a second account can breach your privacy and send your account's data to Microsoft?

Comment: @schroeder Yes. But not in the malware-sense. I mean, is it _officially_ sending data about the "computer" or only about that account.

Comment: One can easily assume that if it is sending account-level data, that it will also send system-level data.